# Is enum type cross-platform in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, enums, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the size of an enum type data in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115550/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-type-data-in-c)

How is enum data type stored internally (I'd imagine as 8/16/32-bit int?) and can it be safely serialized or should I use something like quint8 to store the value? In other words is `sizeof(MyEnum)` guaranteed to be the same size on all platforms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In other words is sizeof(MyEnum) guaranteed to be the same size on all platforms?

You can set an explicit type in C++11 (but *not* in earlier C++ incarnations):

```
enum class Drug : char {
    Cocaine,
    Cannabis,
    Crack
};
```

or

```
enum Sex : uint32_t {
    Male,
    Female,
    Other
};
```

Using `class` in front of `enum` by the way forces users of `Drug` to spell it `Drug::Cocaine`, for enumerations without the `class` in front of their declarations, the spelling is optional (both `Sex::Male` and `Female` are valid).

Hacks for C++es prior 2011 include the following, which forces a minimal size:

```
enum Frob {
    ...
    FORCE_DWORD          = 0x7fffffff
};
```

Seen in practice e.g. on ReactOS' [DirectX-SDK implementation](http://doxygen.reactos.org/dd/df8/d3d8types_8h_a8ef2b49d3b5f6e59fdc4fd76d252b764.html).

---

#### Standards references

> #### 7.2 Enumeration Declarations [dcl.enum]
>
> [...]
>
> §6: For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed, **the underlying type is an integral type that can
> represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. If no integral type can represent all the
> enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed. It is implementation-defined which integral type is used**
> as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int unless the value of an
> enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is
> as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.

Comment: +1, wasn't expecting sex and drugs in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's Friday, people are thinking about the weekend already ;)

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not.  A lot of characteristics of enums are implementation defined.  Make sure to pick a real (safe) type and serialize that.

Answer (score 1):

Size of enum is the same as `int`, so it's not guaranteed to be of the same length everywhere.

Use one of types defined in `stdint.h`, like `int32_t`, `int16_t`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It will generally be the same as an int, which can be of different sizes. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/366026/193892)