# Changing data size of enumerated types C++

Tags: c++, mfc, enums, size

By default enumerated type variables take the size of integer i.e 4 bytes in memory. Is there any way to convert this to any other data type size.

Am not talking about type casting, but the memory size required to store an enumerated type.[I have referred this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115550/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-type-data-in-c) But it didn't tell about changing the integer size to any other.Any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

c++11 introduced [strongly typed enums](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum) (and [Strongly Typed Enums (Revision 3)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf)), which permits the specification of the underlying integral type:

```
#include <iostream>

enum E_ushort : unsigned short { EUS_1, EUS_2 };
enum E_ulong : unsigned long { EUL_1, EUL_2 };

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(E_ushort::EUS_1) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(E_ulong::EUL_1) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
```

Comment: This means if we declare an enum like this it will take the size of unsigned short? Can you explain a little more.

Comment: Yes, it will take the size of an `unsigned short`. I am unsure what else to explain about it. c++11 introduced this feature (see link in answer).

Answer (score 0):

by reading some documentation [on this website](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/45-enumerated-types/) i think it's not possible. In fact it's logical. An enum list just a list with item's referenced by numbers. So, first question which type or you looking at? do you need an enum list who the nomber of item's are to bing for a int ? Or, are you looking at an other type like float char long.. in this case i don't think it's possible