# Why does sizeof enum return a certain value

Tags: enums, typedef, sizeof

I was wondering what the size of my enum type was, so I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum port_config_e {
    CFG_MDIX,       
    CFG_FRAMEMAX,   
    CFG_OFF_ON_DC,  
    CFG_AUTONEG_EN, 
    CFG_DUPLEX_SET, 
    CFG_LOOPBACK,   
    CFG_INGRESS_RATE,
    CFG_EGRESS_RATE,

}port_config_t;

int main(void)
{

printf("%d\n",sizeof(port_config_t));
return 0;
}
```

but I can not understand the result.  Why is the sizeof this enum type 4 Bytes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the size of an enum type data in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115550/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-type-data-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each enum has a value (int). The value is coded in 4 bytes (or 32 bits) for 32-bits computers.

```
0000  CFG_MDIX
0001  CFG_FRAMEMAX
0010  CFG_OFF_ON_DC
0011  CFG_AUTONEG_EN
[...]
```

And why each enum is an Int ? Because it's faster and simpler for the computer to compare int than char* (for example).

Thank you Jashaszun for the correction.

Comment: The value is not coded in 4 bits (an `int` is usually 4 *bytes*, or 32 *bits*). Also, it is "32-bit", not "x32".