# Can sizeof(enum) differ from sizeof(std::underlying_type<Enum>::type)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Recently came up in a code review that in the following example:

```
enum class A : uint8_t
{
    VAL1, VAL2 
};

...
std::vector<A> vOfA; // Assume this is sized and full of some stuff.
std::memcpy(wire_buffer, vOfA.data(), vOfA.size() * sizeof(A));
```

We should be using `sizeof(std::underlying_type<A>::type)` instead of `sizeof(A)`. **Is it possible that these can ever differ?** Does someone have a standards quote that guarantees this?

Comment: Linking [what is the size of an enum type data in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8115550/9305398) (which should be made to cover scoped ones too :-).

Comment: Even if they're the same size (which is more than likely the case), what's the argument against using `sizeof(A)` ? Also : if they're a different size (unlikely), using `sizeof(std::underlying_type<A>)` would be plain wrong.

Comment: `sizeof(std::underlying_type<A>)` is probably `1`. Did you mean `::type`?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Yeah, when dealing with `A`s, one definitely wants to use `sizeof(A)` and the code should not care what kind of type `A` is.

Comment: @L.F. Yep, typo. The title had it correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++03 it was guaranteed (well, for unscoped enumerations anyway).

> **[dcl.enum]**  Enumeration declarations (emphasis mine)
>
> 6 The underlying type of an enumeration is an integral type that can
>   represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. If no
>   integral type can represent all the enumerator values, the enumeration
>   is ill-formed. It is implementation-defined which integral type is
>   used as the underlying type for an enumeration except that the
>   underlying type shall not be larger than int unless the value of an
>   enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int. If the
>   enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration
>   had a single enumerator with value 0. **The value of `sizeof()` applied
>   to an enumeration type, an object of enumeration type, or an
>   enumerator, is the value of `sizeof()` applied to the underlying type**.

Then came [n2347](https://wg21.link/n2347), the paper that was adopted for strongly typed enumerations (`enum class`) and other enhancements to unscoped enumerations, and it had the sentence in bold removed. Interestingly enough, an earlier version of the proposal, [n2213](http://wg21.link/n2213), had a replacement for the removed sentence. But it didn't make into the version that was adopted.

So in modern C++, there is no obligation for the sizes to be the same. Though from a practical standpoint, implementations are unlikely to have changed the behavior prescribed by C++03 for enumeration sizes.

One could deem it a defect in the standard.

Comment: How can something have been guaranteed in C++03 for a feature that didn't exist in the language? o.O

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica - The notion of an underlying type isn't new. It's just that C++11 allowed you to specify it yourself.

Comment: I know that. The notion of a scoped enum (`enum class`) is new.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica - I think one can potentially fault the proposal here. It did two things, introduced scoped enumerations and allowed all enumerations (not just scoped ones) to have their underlying type set. Hence the "guaranteed" in C++03.

Comment: I'm just saying, you claim that `sizeof(a scoped enum) == sizeof(underlying type)` is guaranted in C++03, when one of those things did not actually exist at the time.

Comment: Besides, we can change the OP to use an unscoped enumeration without changing the question.

Comment: The question doesn't know that :)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yeah, the question is the same i think, scoped or unscoped.